# Can I use reflection with RealProxy instances?

Tags: c#, reflection, clr, proxy-classes

I'm quite sure I'm missing some constraint or caveat somewhere, but here's my situation. Assume I have a class that I want to have a proxy for, like the following:

```
public class MyList : MarshalByRefObject, IList<string>
{
    private List<string> innerList;

    public MyList(IEnumerable<string> stringList)
    {
        this.innerList = new List<string>(stringList);
    }

    // IList<string> implementation omitted for brevity.
    // For the sake of this exercise, assume each method
    // implementation merely passes through to the associated
    // method on the innerList member variable.
}
```

I want to create a proxy for that class, so that I can intercept method calls and perform some processing on the underlying object. Here is my implementation:

```
public class MyListProxy : RealProxy
{
    private MyList actualList;

    private MyListProxy(Type typeToProxy, IEnumerable<string> stringList)
        : base(typeToProxy)
    {
        this.actualList = new MyList(stringList);
    }

    public static object CreateProxy(IEnumerable<string> stringList)
    {
        MyListProxy listProxy = new MyListProxy(typeof(MyList), stringList);
        object foo =  listProxy.GetTransparentProxy();
        return foo;
    }

    public override IMessage Invoke(IMessage msg)
    {
        IMethodCallMessage callMsg = msg as IMethodCallMessage;
        MethodInfo proxiedMethod = callMsg.MethodBase as MethodInfo;
        return new ReturnMessage(proxiedMethod.Invoke(actualList, callMsg.Args), null, 0, callMsg.LogicalCallContext, callMsg);
    }
}
```

Finally, I have a class that consumes the proxied class, and I set the value of the `MyList` member via reflection.

```
public class ListConsumer
{
    public MyList MyList { get; protected set; }

    public ListConsumer()
    {
        object listProxy = MyListProxy.CreateProxy(new List<string>() { "foo", "bar", "baz", "qux" });
        PropertyInfo myListPropInfo = this.GetType().GetProperty("MyList");
        myListPropInfo.SetValue(this, listProxy);
    }
}
```

Now, if I try to use reflection to access the proxied object, I run into problems. Here is an example:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ListConsumer listConsumer = new ListConsumer();

        // These calls merely illustrate that the property can be
        // properly accessed and methods called through the created
        // proxy without issue.
        Console.WriteLine("List contains {0} items", listConsumer.MyList.Count);
        Console.WriteLine("List contents:");
        foreach(string stringValue in listConsumer.MyList)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(stringValue);
        }

        Type listType = listConsumer.MyList.GetType();
        foreach (Type interfaceType in listType.GetInterfaces())
        {
            if (interfaceType.IsGenericType && interfaceType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(ICollection<>))
            {
                // Attempting to get the value of the Count property via
                // reflection throws an exception.
                Console.WriteLine("Checking interface {0}", interfaceType.Name);
                System.Reflection.PropertyInfo propInfo = interfaceType.GetProperty("Count");
                int count = (int)propInfo.GetValue(listConsumer.MyList, null);
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Skipping interface {0}", interfaceType.Name);
            }
        }

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Attempting to call `GetValue` on the `Count` property via reflection throws the following exception:

> An exception of type 'System.Reflection.TargetException' occurred in
>   mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: Object does not match target type.

When attempting to get the value of the `Count` property, apparently the framework is calling down into `System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime.IVector` to call the `get_Size` method. I'm not understanding how this call fails on the underlying object of the proxy (the actual list) to make this happen. If I'm not using a proxy of the object, getting the property value works fine via reflection. What am I doing wrong? Can I even do what I'm trying to accomplish?

**Edit:** A [bug has been opened](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/1853289) regarding this issue at the Microsoft Connect site.

Comment: Note this implementation isn't idle speculation. [MbUnit's `Assert.Count` method](https://github.com/Gallio/mbunit-v3/blob/master/src/MbUnit/MbUnit/Framework/Assert.Count.cs) does this for some collections. If the collection object is a proxy the call to `Assert.Count` throws.

Comment: Is it possible to make the `MyListProxy.CreateProxy` generic, so that it returns the real type and not type object? For the test: if this call in main `interfaceType.GetProperty("Count")` is changed to `((MyList)interfaceType).GetProperty("Count")` does then the call to `Count`work?

Comment: similar problems here - using Invoke() appears to cause marshalling which causes execution to fall into this VectorToCollectionAdapter which then barfs with the message "Object does not match target type." (because an IVector is not an ICollection). I consider this to be a bug.

Comment: @JimEvans did you file a bug at https://connect.microsoft.com/ for this? If not one of us could...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think this may be a bug in the .Net framework. Somehow the `RuntimePropertyInfo.GetValue` method is picking the wrong implementation for the `ICollection<>.Count` property, and it appears to have to do with WindowsRuntime projections. Perhaps the remoting code was redone when they put the WindowsRuntime interop in the framework.

I switched the framework to target .Net 2.0 since I thought if this was a bug, it shouldn't be in that framework. When converting, Visual Studio removed the "Prefer 32 bit" check on my console exe project (since this doesn't exist in 2.0). It runs without exception when this is not present.

In summary, it runs on .Net 2.0 in both 32 and 64 bit. It runs on .Net 4.x in 64 bit. The exception is thrown on .Net 4.x 32 bit only. This sure looks like a bug. If you can run it 64-bit, that would be a workaround.

Note that I've installed .Net 4.6, and this replaces much of the .Net framework v4.x. It could be this is where the problem is introduced; I can't test until I get a machine that doesn't have .Net 4.6.

*Update: 2015-09-08*

It also happens on a machine with only .Net 4.5.2 installed (no 4.6).

*Update: 2015-09-07*

Here's a smaller repro, using your same classes:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var myList = MyListProxy.CreateProxy(new[] {"foo", "bar", "baz", "quxx"});
    var listType = myList.GetType();
    var interfaceType = listType.GetInterface("System.Collections.Generic.ICollection`1");
    var propInfo = interfaceType.GetProperty("Count");

    // TargetException thrown on 32-bit .Net 4.5.2+ installed
    int count = (int)propInfo.GetValue(myList, null); 
}
```

I've also tried the `IsReadOnly` property, but it appears to work (no exception).

---

As to the source of the bug, there are two layers of indirection around properties, one being the remoting, and the other being a mapping of metadata structures called `MethodDef`s with the actual runtime method, known internally as a `MethodDesc`. [This mapping is specialized for properties (as well as events), where additional `MethodDesc`s to support the property's get/set PropertyInfo instances are known as `Associates`](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/blob/master/src/vm/method.hpp#L1516). By calling `PropertyInfo.GetValue` we go through one of these Associate `MethodDesc` pointers to the underlying method implementation, and remoting does some pointer math to get the correct `MethodDesc` on the other side of the channel. The CLR code is very convoluted here, and I don't have enough experience of the in-memory layout of the `MethodTable` which holds these `MethodDesc` records which remoting uses (or the mapping it uses to get to the MethodTable?), but I'd say it's a fair guess that remoting is grabbing the wrong `MethodDesc` via some bad pointer math. That's why we see a similar but unrelated (as far as your program) `MethodDesc` - `UInt32 get_Size` of `IVector<T>` being invoked on the call:

```
System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.CheckConsistency(Object target)
System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.InvokeArgumentsCheck(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
System.Reflection.MethodBase.Invoke(Object obj, Object[] parameters)
ConsoleApplication1.MyListProxy.Invoke(IMessage msg) Program.cs: line: 60
System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)
System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime.IVector`1.get_Size()
System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime.VectorToCollectionAdapter.Count[T]()
```

Answer (score 11):

This is a pretty interesting CLR bug, some of its guts are showing in the mishap.  You can tell from the stack trace that it is trying to call the [VectorToCollectionAdapter](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/runtime/interopservices/windowsruntime/vectortocollectionadapter.cs,ff787a63edbc2ac6)'s Count property.

This class is rather special, no instance of it ever gets created.  It is part of the *language projection* that was added in .NET 4.5 that makes WinRT interface types look like .NET Framework types.  It is pretty similar to the SZArrayHelper class, an adapter class that helps implement the illusion that non-generic arrays implement generic interface types like `IList<T>`.

The interface mapping at work here is for the WinRT [`IVector<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/BR206631.aspx) interface.  As noted in the MSDN article, that interface type is mapped to `IList<T>`.  The internal VectorToListAdapter class takes care of the `IList<T>` members, VectorToCollectionAdapter tackles the `ICollection<T>` members.

Your code forces the CLR to find the implementation of ICollection<>.Count and that could either be a .NET class implementing it as normal or it could be a WinRT object that exposes it as IVector<>.Size.  Clearly the proxy you created gives it a headache, it incorrectly decided for the WinRT version.

How it is *supposed* to figure out which is the correct choice is pretty murky.  After all, your proxy *could* be a proxy for an actual WinRT object and then the choice it made would be correct.  This could well be a structural problem.  That it acts so randomly, the code does work in 64-bit mode, is not exactly inspiring.  VectorToCollectionAdapter is very dangerous, note the JitHelpers.UnsafeCast calls, this bug is potentially exploitable.

Well, alert the authorities, file a bug report at connect.microsoft.com. Let me know if you don't want to take the time and I'll take care of it.  A workaround is hard to come by, using the WinRT-centric TypeInfo class to do the reflection did not make any difference.  Removing the jitter forcing so it runs in 64-bit mode is a band-aid but hardly a guarantee.

Answer (score 4):

we are currently hacking around this problem with this brittle intervention (apologies for code):

```
public class ProxyBase : RealProxy
{
    // ... stuff ...

    public static T Cast<T>(object o)
    {
        return (T)o;
    }

    public static object Create(Type interfaceType, object coreInstance, 
        IEnforce enforce, string parentNamingSequence)
    {
        var x = new ProxyBase(interfaceType, coreInstance, enforce, 
            parentNamingSequence);

        MethodInfo castMethod = typeof(ProxyBase).GetMethod(
            "Cast").MakeGenericMethod(interfaceType);

        return castMethod.Invoke(null, new object[] { x.GetTransparentProxy() });
    }

    public override IMessage Invoke(IMessage msg)
    {
        IMethodCallMessage methodCall = (IMethodCallMessage)msg;
        var method = (MethodInfo)methodCall.MethodBase;

        if(method.DeclaringType.IsGenericType
        && method.DeclaringType.GetGenericTypeDefinition().FullName.Contains(
            "System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime"))
        {
            Dictionary<string, string> methodMap = new Dictionary<string, string>
            {   // add problematic methods here
                { "Append", "Add" },
                { "GetAt", "get_Item" }
            };

            if(methodMap.ContainsKey(method.Name) == false)
            {
                throw new Exception("Unable to resolve '" + method.Name + "'.");
            }
            // thanks microsoft
            string correctMethod = methodMap[method.Name];
            method = m_baseInterface.GetInterfaces().Select(
                i => i.GetMethod(correctMethod)).Where(
                    mi => mi != null).FirstOrDefault();

            if(method == null)
            {
                throw new Exception("Unable to resolve '" + method.Name + 
                    "' to '" + correctMethod + "'.");
            }
        }

        try
        {
            if(m_coreInstance == null)
            {
                var errorMessage = Resource.CoreInstanceIsNull;
                WriteLogs(errorMessage, TraceEventType.Error);
                throw new NullReferenceException(errorMessage);
            }

            var args = methodCall.Args.Select(a =>
            {
                object o;

                if(RemotingServices.IsTransparentProxy(a))
                {
                    o = (RemotingServices.GetRealProxy(a) 
                        as ProxyBase).m_coreInstance;
                }
                else
                {
                    o = a;
                }

                if(method.Name == "get_Item")
                {   // perform parameter conversions here
                    if(a.GetType() == typeof(UInt32))
                    { 
                        return Convert.ToInt32(a);
                    }

                    return a;                            
                }

                return o;
            }).ToArray();
            // this is where it barfed
            var result = method.Invoke(m_coreInstance, args);
            // special handling for GetType()
            if(method.Name == "GetType")
            {
                result = m_baseInterface;
            }
            else
            {
                // special handling for interface return types
                if(method.ReturnType.IsInterface)
                {
                    result = ProxyBase.Create(method.ReturnType, result, m_enforce, m_namingSequence);
                }
            }

            return new ReturnMessage(result, args, args.Length, methodCall.LogicalCallContext, methodCall);
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            WriteLogs("Exception: " + e, TraceEventType.Error);
            if(e is TargetInvocationException && e.InnerException != null)
            {
                return new ReturnMessage(e.InnerException, msg as IMethodCallMessage);
            }
            return new ReturnMessage(e, msg as IMethodCallMessage);
        }
    }

    // ... stuff ...
}
```

m_coreInstance here is the object instance that the proxy is wrapping.

m_baseInterface is the interface the object is to be used as.

this code intercepts the call(s) made in VectorToListAdapter and VectorToCollectionAdapter and converts it back into the original via that methodMap dictionary.

the part of the conditional:

```
method.DeclaringType.GetGenericTypeDefinition().FullName.Contains(
        "System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime")
```

makes sure it only intercepts calls that come from stuff in the System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime namespace - ideally we would target the types directly but they are inaccessible - this should probably be changed to target specific class names in the namespace.

the parameters are then cast into the appropriate types and the method is invoked. the parameter conversions appear to be necessary as the incoming parameter types are based on the parameter types of the method calls **from** the objects in the System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime namespace, and not the parameters of the method calls **to** the original object types; i.e. the original types before the objects in the System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime namespace hijacked the mechanism.

for example, the WindowsRuntime stuff intercepts the original call to get_Item, and converts it into a call to the Indexer_Get method: http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/runtime/interopservices/windowsruntime/vectortolistadapter.cs,de8c78a8f98213a0,references. this method then calls the GetAt member with a different parameter type, which then calls GetAt on our object (again with a different parameter type) - this is the call we hijack in our Invoke() and convert it back into the original method call with the original parameter types.

it would be nice to be able to reflect over VectorToListAdapter and VectorToCollectionAdapter to extract all their methods and the nested calls they make, but these classes are unfortunately marked as internal.

this works for us here, but i'm sure its full of holes - it is a case of trial and error, running it to see what fails and then adding in the required dictionary entries/parameter conversions. we are continuing the search for a better solution.

HTH